# Running Cypress Tests from Jenkins from bitbucket without exposing credentials saved in fixtures files

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, cypress

I have a API testcase. I have saved Authorization details like client creds stored in fixtures.(cred.json)

While pushing the code to bitbucket we are ignoring that file to avoid credentials to be stored in bitbucket.

Now when I run from Jenkins with bitbucket it fails as credentials are not given. Is there any way  to run successfully without exposing credentials?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. How can you run the test without credentials if that's required? Are you asking how to store credentials safely in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

you can send your creds in Jenkins via command for cypress:

"ENV_URL=https://your_url USERNAME=admin npm run cy:run"

command in package.json

cy:run: "cypress run --env urlConfig=$ENV_URL,user=$USERNAME --browser chrome

and it is safe way to use sensitive data without saving in repo

documentation:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env